# Formatting multilevel JSON data in PHP from remote file [SOLVED]

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to extract json data from a remote php file (not a json file) so that it each time the page is propagated it pulls the newest data to format. Here are examples of what I am trying to accomplish but I cant get it to work.

resc_payouts.php

```
{"number":1,"username":"ivalenel"},{"number":2,"username":"newb-6763"},{"number":3,"username":"jeremyhipps"},{"number":4,"username":"dcollier200"},{"number":5,"username":"AdrianEric311"},{"number":6,"username":"Prxnce24"},{"number":7,"username":"Bungy2004"},{"number":8,"username":"sevyf7"},{"number":9,"username":"jerocker79"},{"number":10,"username":"Djmoonknight8"},{"number":11,"username":"marcel_g_l"},{"number":12,"username":"zebuss"},{"number":13,"username":"fourZer0"},{"number":14,"username":"himalayabpatel"},{"number":15,"username":"Chip1234"},{"number":16,"username":"AsvpJ9k"},{"number":17,"username":"himmy23"},{"number":18,"username":"Chip1234"},{"number":19,"username":"Clares20"},{"number":20,"username":"ballermoss"},{"number":21,"username":"gareagan04"},{"number":22,"username":"cweatherfordinc"}
```

jsontest.php

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('https://**********.com/manage/resc_payouts.php');
$decoded_json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($decoded_json as $key => $value) {
    $username = $decoded_json[$key]["username"];
    echo $username;
}
?>
```

I have tried many methods, converting to a string, encoding and then decoding but cant seem to figure this out. Any help on getting this remote data off a php file and formatting it would be immensely useful.

Comment: When the data _is not_ JSON, then what sense could it possibly make to try and parse it _as JSON_?

Comment: What is the content of this `resc_payouts.php` actually supposed to be? Because what you have shown us, appears to be just a bunch of `var_dump` debug outputs. That is not a method suitable to prepare data for "transport" in the first place. Are you in charge of that file, and what exactly it outputs?

Comment: resc_payouts.php it should be a json file. `resc_payouts.json`

Comment: @CBroe So there is no way to parse a php file if the contents are just a json payload? i would think i could get file contents. encode it and decode it... or am i wrong

Comment: You can go to the URL and see the json output

Comment: @DirtyTech If you found a solution, then answer your own question using the field below and mark the answer as accepted.  The question body is only for text concerning the question; not answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @DirtyTech Please remove [solved] from your question title and instead click the checkmark next to the answer.  That is what we use to indicate a question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

So after a few hours i found a solution

```
SOLUTION FOUND
```

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('https://**********.com/manage/resc_payouts.php');

$json = json_decode($content, TRUE); // decode the JSON into an associative array

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['number'];
    echo $value['username'];
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Thanks but i figured this out myself over time